# Xamarin Forms, how to log unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, error-logging

I have following code in my Xamarin Forms project. I used SentryErrorLog to log exception and saved exception message to pp device locally. I have tested following code and the logging is successful. But I found when there is an unknown exception causing App crashed, there is no log in Sentry and in ExternalStorageDirectory. The unknown exception caused the App shutdown and popup an message "{App name} has stopped".

Because there is no log of the exception, so I don't know how to investigate it. And this exception only happens sometimes, it's hard for me to find the reason. So I want to know if I missed any code to catch the exception? Or sometimes the Android closes the App before the App triggers the exception event handler?

```
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        ravenClient = SentryErrorLog.CreateRavenClient();
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
    }

    private void AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        ravenClient.LogException(e.Exception);
        LogExceptionLocally(e.Exception);
    }

    private void LogExceptionLocally(Exception e)
    {
        // Log to ExternalStorageDirectory
    }
```

Or maybe I should use other crash logger?

Answer (score 1):

you can add these codes below to log unhandled exception:

Android:

```
// In OnCreate,

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironmentOnUnhandledException;
```

iOS:

```
// In FinishedLaunching:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += async (sender, e) =>
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += async (sender, e) =>
```

UWP:

```
// In OnLaunched:

UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
```

and here are some links that might help:

[Logging Xamarin unhandled (Android uncaught) exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785747/logging-xamarin-unhandled-android-uncaught-exceptions)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103962/go-back-to-mainpage-if-there-is-an-unhandled-exception

Comment: I tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;`. I throw an exception manually for test, and I found both `UnhandledException` and `UnhandledExceptionRaiser` were triggered, so I got 2 logs for one exception. Duplicated log is not expected. What is the difference between this 2 events? I just worry about that maybe OS shut down the app before app starts to log exception.

Comment: Don't worry about that. If you app is crashed due to an exception in your app,you app could log exception before it shut down.

Comment: Actually,there is not so much difference between these two events.You can refer to  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3071/clarification-on-unhandledexception-vs-unhandledexceptionraiser to view the difference.

Comment: thanks for your help, after I added the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, I caught the exception which is an AndroidRuntime error. But the `UnhandledExceptionRaiser` didn't catch it. So looks the `UnhandledException` handler can catch wider range of exception? According to your above link, looks the `UnhandledExceptionRaiser` translates the .NET exception to an appropriate Java-side exception, which may be necessary in some situation? Can I only use the `UnhandledException`? I will get duplicated logs if I add both.

Comment: You can only use `UnhandledException`. And refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser/ to know what `UnhandledExceptionRaiser` do.